# Usage of String.range in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let us = "http://example.com"
let range = us.rangeOfString("(?<=://)[^.]+(?=.com)", options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
if range != nil {
    let found = us.substringWithRange(range!)
    print("found: \(found)") // found: example
}
```

This code extracts `substring` between backslashes and dot com in Swift 2. I searched Internet and I found that `rangeOfString` changed to `range()`.

But still I could not make the code work in Swift 3.0. Could you help me ?

edit : I'm using swift 3 07-25 build.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**In swift 3.0** `rangeOfString` syntax changed like this.

```
let us = "http://example.com"
let range = us.range(of:"(?<=://)[^.]+(?=.com)", options:.regularExpression)
if range != nil {
     let found = us.substring(with: range!)
     print("found: \(found)") // found: example
}
```

Comment: it gives following errors:

1- Type 'CompareOptions' (aka 'NSString.CompareOptions') has no member 'RegularExpressionSearch'

2- Value of type 'String' has no member 'substringWithRange'

Comment: @H.Cliff check an answer below for latest SDK

Comment: @LeoDabus editted for that. Sorry forgot to set that also for swift 3.

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :) but i'm `NDoc`

Answer (score 7):

In latest swift 3.0 using Xcode 8 Beta 6 (latest updates to SDK):

```
let us = "http://example.com"
let range = us.range(of: "(?<=://)[^.]+(?=.com)", options: .regularExpression)
if range != nil {
    let found = us.substring(with: range!)
    print("found: \(found)") // found: example
}
```