# Filter an array defined by a Struct

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Trying to find a way to filter an array in Swift 3 that is defined with a Struct

```
// Define Structures
struct manufacturer {
    var manuShort = String();
    var manufacturer = String();
}

var manufacturerArray = [manufacturer]()

var arryDeptTemp = self.manufacturerArray.filter { $0.manufacturer.rangeOfString("3M", options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil }
```

I am getting an error on the filter indicating `Value of Type String has no member rangeOfString

Do I just have the syntax wrong or is there a problem trying to filter like this?

I was able to resolve this with:

```
    var filteredArray = self.manufacturerArray.filter { $0.manufacturer.range(of: srchVal, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

So perhaps it was a syntax thing?

Comment: It is `range(of:)` in Swift 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126003/usage-of-string-range-in-swift-3-0 (first Google hit for "swift 3 rangeofstring")

Comment: Note that your error is unrelated to arrays or to filtering.

Comment: I don't see the point of trying to get a Range if you just want to check if a substring exists. IMO, a better filter would be: `$0.manufacturer.lowercased().contains("3m")`

Comment: @Abizern I am try to product a filtered subset of the original array.

Comment: A filter includes all elements where the closure evaluates to `true`